# Fetching and rendering data from Reddit/REST API

Tags: javascript, api, ecmascript-6, fetch-api, reddit

***DISCLAIMER:** I'm a designer trying to learn more javascript. Go easy on me.*

I'm creating a site that fetches and renders posts from the reddit api and displays the data in a CSS grid/newspaper style layout. Similar to The Verge. Here's my code so far:

```
const url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/upliftingnews.json?raw_json=1&limit=10"

fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => res.data.children)
    .then(res => res.map(post => ({
        author: post.data.author,
        link: post.data.url,
        img: (typeof (post.data.preview) !== 'undefined') ? post.data.preview.images[0].source.url : null,
        // img: post.data.thumbnail,
        title: post.data.title
    })))
    .then(res => res.map(render))
    .then(res => console.log(res))

// fetch(url)
//     .then(response => response.json())
//     .then(response => {
//         console.log(response.data.children[1].data.preview.images[0].resolutions[1].url);
//     });


const app = document.querySelector('#app');

const render = post => {
    //console.log(post.data);
    const node = document.createElement('div');
    node.innerHTML = `
    <h2>
      <a href="${post.link}">
        <img src="${post.img}" />
        ${post.title}
      </a>
    </h2>`;
    app.appendChild(node);
}
```

So this works fine but is there a more efficient/performant way I should be doing this? My problem is:

1. I don't really have any control over the markup for individual rendered posts. I could use use CSS and nth-child to style posts individually, but that seems inefficient.
2. It doesn't seem very performant. The html renders in 1 or 2 seconds after the page has loaded causing a blank screen flash.

Googling anything to do with fetch api's/rendering json brings up results related to react/vue/angular/insertJSLibraryHere.

Should I realistically be using one of these frameworks? Would it be easier/more effective if I just learned how to use React for this? I've been avoiding learning React/Vue because I just find it so difficult to wrap my head around but maybe this is a good place to start?

It's difficult to find answers to this when every search results is related to some JS framework. Hence why I am asking here.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic fetch example in React.**

It's a better practice to save your response from your api call in a state array from a componentWillMount lifecycle method. Also I'd like to use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) instead of fetch.

Here is a example:

```
import axios from 'axios';

class someComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            redditItems: [];
        }
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        axios.get(API_URL).then(res => {
            this.setState({ redditItems: res.data.data.children });
        }).catch(err => {
            // CODE WHEN FAILS.
        });
    }

    renderList = () => {
        return this.state.reditItems.map((item, i) => (
            <div key={ i }>
                <p>{ item.data.url }</p>
                <p>{ item.data.author }</p>
            </div> // HOW YOU WANT TO DISPLAY YOUR ITEM
        ));
    }

    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.renderList() }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not using React. My question is whether I am better suited using something like React for this or is that unnecessary when I can do it all in vanilla JS.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. You definitely can do this like you did with the fetch api. I suggest reading [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data) (if you haven't done that already). For the performance issue you ran into, it is always a good idea to render placeholder data before your api call. So when it's loaded it will be replaced with your real data. After all i think it's not a bad idea to start learning a framework like Vue or React. You will be surprised how much fun it is to work with.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I think you edited your comment but I've switched out fetch in favour of async/await. When I can find time, I'll properly look into react.